# wifi direct with laptop

Tags: wifi-direct

Are there laptops / wireless cards that I can purchase to allow my laptop use Wifi-direct to communicate with my smartphone? Say, to transfer files between them? I have seen phones that support that technology but not computer components yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the list of certified products on the Wi-Fi Alliance website :

- [Laptops](http://certifications.wi-fi.org/search_products.php?search=1&advanced=1&lang=en&filter_company_id=&filter_category_id=20&filter_subcategory=&filter_cid=&date_from=&date_to=&selected_certifications%5B%5D=50&x=61&y=13)
- [External adapters](http://certifications.wi-fi.org/search_products.php?search=1&advanced=1&lang=en&filter_company_id=&filter_category_id=3&filter_subcategory=&filter_cid=&date_from=&date_to=&x=58&y=14&selected_certifications%5B%5D=50)
- [Internal adapters](http://certifications.wi-fi.org/search_products.php?search=1&advanced=1&lang=en&filter_company_id=&filter_category_id=2&filter_subcategory=&filter_cid=&date_from=&date_to=&x=16&y=19&selected_certifications%5B%5D=50)

For another type of product use the [search engine](http://certifications.wi-fi.org/search_products.php?advanced=1&en) and tick the Wi-fi Direct checkbox at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks. But I thought those lists are for Wi-Fi certified, not Wi-Fi Direct certified products?

Comment: Not if you check the Wifi-Direct checkbox at the bottom of the search page.